# react-native-image-picker uri doesn't persist for android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker

according to the documentation:

> On iOS, don't assume that the absolute uri returned will persist. See #107

I'm testing it on my android(Xiaomi) device and it works fine when I choose an image, but after closing the app and opening it again or re-running it using `react-native run-android`, the `uri` doesn't work anymore and instead of the image, I get a blueish color.
this is my code:

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker({
   storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true
   }
}, res => {
   // handling error, etc.
   this.setState({image: res.uri});
   // persisting with AsyncStorage
   }
);

//then showing it
<Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{ uri: this.state.image }}/>
```

[image: after re-opening the app]
this is my uri after restarting the app:
`content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FIMG_20190310_123752.jpg`

It's strange because when I get the bluish color and again choose the same picture from my gallery I get the same uri as above and it works!!!although
it's the same as before restarting. what can I do? thanks

Comment: I don't have the same issue, but I heard developers usually use redux-persist for android.

Comment: @Ziyo yes, this is exactly what I did, but I don't know why this happens?! is anything wrong with my code? on the other hand, the picture that I choose or take with the camera doesn't appear in the `pictures` directory! is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

For Android, you can use `response.path` instead `response.uri` to get the real file path on the device.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md

Don't forget to prepend `file:///` to response.path so if I take your code:

```
...
this.setState({image: "file:///" + res.path});
...
```

`response.uri` seems to be temporary path which it's kill at the same time app is close.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of resolving this issue is to disable the cache for your images, however I always overcome this by adding an **extra parameter** at the end of url to make it different than before, so with this way you'll trick the os(android in your case).
The code is changed to something like this:

```
<Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri:'your_image_link.com/image.jpg?ts=Math.random()' }}/>
```

this will add a unique tail to your uri that prevents caching.
Don't forget that you need to put `'your_image_link.com/image.jpg?ts=Math.random()'` in your **setState()**.
Good luck!

Comment: how can I `disable the cache`?

Comment: have a look on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-requests-for-images . However, I never tried since it's supported (i think) for ios(have a look on this too :https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#cache-control-ios-only)

Comment: thanks but your solution didn't solve my problem, it also prevented my image from showing at the first time

Comment: Sorry, seems I missunderstood  the issue

Answer (score 0):

When we taking an image using `launchCamera()` method, the image is saved in a temporary location so the Image can be deleted at any time, You need to move or copy that Image into Storage. You can use *react-native-fs* package to copy or move that image from a temporary location to Storage. `launchCamera()` return temporary location uri, you can use that uri to perform a move or copy function.

This method allows you to take multiple images and upload them after taking images.